# contracts/SimpleStorage.sol:5:5: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. unit256 favoriteNumber; ^-----^

Tags: solidity

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStograge {
    unit256 favoriteNumber;

    function store(unit256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

simple code but getting this error can anyone help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `unit256` to `uint256` and try to compile.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStograge {
    uint256 favoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

More information about types [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html).